# PHP simplehtmldom adding attributes

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

For a project, I need to grab a page (ANY page on the internet) and manipulate it. I am using simplehtmldom for this ([found here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)), since it is easy and works like a charm.. mostly.. I need to set a class attribute to certain elements, some of which do have a class attribute already, some of which don't. According to [this article](http://grinninggecko.com/php-simple-html-dom-parser/) i found, you can add an attribute the following way:

```
$value = $e->attr['data-role'];
```

This, unfortunately, does not work for me. The following code gives these errors:

```
if(!isset($elem->class))
{
    $elem->attr['class'] = "classname";
}
else
{
    $elem->class = $elem->class . " classname";
}

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in simplehtmldom.php on line 483
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in simplehtmldom.php on line 488
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in simplehtmldom.php on line 494
```

Which is the following in simplehtmldom:

```
function makeup()
{
    // text, comment, unknown
    if (isset($this->_[HDOM_INFO_TEXT])) return $this->dom->restore_noise($this->_[HDOM_INFO_TEXT]);

    $ret = '<'.$this->tag;
    $i = -1;

    foreach ($this->attr as $key=>$val)
    {
        ++$i;
            // skip removed attribute
        if ($val===null || $val===false)
            continue;
/* 483 */   $ret .= $this->_[HDOM_INFO_SPACE][$i][0];
        //no value attr: nowrap, checked selected...
        if ($val===true)
            $ret .= $key;
        else {
/* 488 */       switch ($this->_[HDOM_INFO_QUOTE][$i])
            {
                case HDOM_QUOTE_DOUBLE: $quote = '"'; break;
                case HDOM_QUOTE_SINGLE: $quote = '\''; break;
                default: $quote = '';
            }
/* 494 */   $ret .= $key.$this->_[HDOM_INFO_SPACE][$i][1].'='.$this->_[HDOM_INFO_SPACE][$i][2].$quote.$val.$quote;
        }
    }
    $ret = $this->dom->restore_noise($ret);
    return $ret . $this->_[HDOM_INFO_ENDSPACE] . '>';
}
```

I'm having some trouble figuring out why it won't work. Is it something that might have changed since the article was written, or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: what can we find in `simplehtmldom.php` at line 483, 488..?

Comment: @MatRt As you can see the code of the simplehtmldom.php is pasted here and the lines are marked. Anyway, I was too fast asking this question (shame on me) and found the answer. Thanks for trying anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was a little too early asking this question. I found [this page](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm#camel) (API reference) and it tells us we can use the following W3C standard too:

```
$e->setAttribute ( $name, $value )
```

So instead of

```
$elem->attr['class'] = "classname";
```

you can do

```
$elem->setAttribute("class","classname");
```

I'll keep the question and answer up in case other people come across this and miss the API reference page.