# how to add attribute rel='no flollow' to all anchor tags inside div [simple html doc]

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match-all, simple-html-dom

I m using simple html doc here to get data from source code and then filtering it to my need

```
//including script
include($config>root.'/script/vendor/simple_html_dom/simple_html_dom.php');

//getting all data
$url = "www.example.com";

$html = file_get_html($url, $use_include_path = false, $context=null, $offset = -1, $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=false, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT , $defaultSpanText=DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT);

//title
$title = $html->find('#question-header h1 a',0)->innertext;

//comments
foreach($html->find('#question .comment-body') as $element) {
$question_comments[] = $element->innertext;
}

//{running a lot of loops like above}

//{than i have a final result inside output}
$output = ob_get_clean();
{here i need some stack help to add attribute to all anchor tags inside a particular div}      
echo $output;   
?>
```

For Example This is what i got in $output variable

$output = "

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='container'>
        <a href='/link-1'></a>
        <div class='data'>
            <a href='/link-2'></a>
            <a href='/link-3'></a>
            <a href='/link-4'></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='footer'>
        <a href='/new-link'></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

";
and i want to add attribute rel='no-follow' to all anchor tags inside container

Comment: Have you tried `DOMDocument`?

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/aomk1nnr/)[link]

Comment: no i haven't tried yet

Comment: @SahilGulati I hope you are spending time to find a duplicate instead of posting an answer.

Comment: yes i looked a lot over stackoverflow but no help

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523099/php-simplehtmldom-adding-attributes

Comment: Answering duplicate questions is poor SO citizenship, not everyone does the right thing.

Comment: @mickmackusa Please read question carefully and see the link on expected output. He want to add attribute in nested HTML inside all `a` inside `container` `div`

Comment: You know this is not the first time this question has been asked on SO.  You just want the rep points, you probably searched SO as long as the OP.

Comment: Find a better duplicate if mine is not suitable.

Comment: (not my downvote by the way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Hope this one will be helpful.

You can remove comments if you want this solution to work with more nested tags as well.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/844863)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string =<<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='container'>
        <a href='/link-1'></a>
        <div class='data'>
            <a href='/link-2'></a>
            <a href='/link-3'></a>
            <a href='/link-4'></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='footer'>
        <a href='/new-link'></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
HTML;

$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($string);

$domXPath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$results = $domXPath->query("//div[@class='container']/*");
foreach($results as $result)
{
    if($result instanceof DOMElement && $result->tagName=="a")
    {
        $result->setAttribute("rel", "no-follow");       
    }
    else
    {
        addAttribute($result);
    }
}

function addAttribute($result)
{
    global $domXPath;
    $results = $domXPath->query("./a",$result);//change query to ./* to make it work with nested HTML. 
    foreach($results as $result)
    {
        if($result instanceof DOMElement && $result->tagName=="a")
        {
            $result->setAttribute("rel", "no-follow");       
        }
        //Uncomment these lines to work with more nested HTML.
        //else 
        //{
        //    addAttribute($result);
        //}
    }
}
echo $domDocument->saveHTML();
```